# Source for not asking your spouse to do something for you

Tags: sources-mekorot, marriage

I recall hearing an idea once that you shouldn't ask your spouse to do something for you, but I'm not sure where it is from.  Does anyone know the source?

Comment: I think "asking" might not be the correct term, maybe "demand"? Otherwise you would not have a giving, reciprocal marriage

Comment: I seem to remember it being put in those terms as I was quite surprised at it being that extreme.  I think perhaps he meant that it was best to minimise asking, and/or perhaps to put it in terms of informing them that you would like it if they did something without any pressure to actually do so.  Clearly communication on needs and desires is needed, which is part of the reason I'm asking!

Comment: I suspect the root of the idea comes from rabbi Shalom Arush

Comment: Not a marriage expert, but that seems idiotic. Also against "ezer knegdo". Avraham asked Sarah for various things.

Comment: @יהושעק maybe, but I think it came from a British/US Charedi Rav (who I suspect is unlikely to follow Rav Arush) - think it was a shiur my wife was listening to years ago

Comment: @N.T. I have always been pretty sceptical about it too, which is part of the reason I'm trying to find a source

Comment: Your skepticism is good. I doubt you will find one.

Comment: @MosesSupposes I can't help but ask ..did you hear this firsthand, or is this exclusively something your wife "relayed" to you? ;)

Comment: @יהושעק I'm going back a number of years, but it was first hand - I think she had a shiur on in the background while she was busy around the house (and I was probably working at my desk), so I didn't get much context.  I really can't imagine that is something that she'd relay to me anyway!

Comment: @N.T. I don't know - I know that there is a concept that אהבה comes from הב - to give, and therefore it makes a certain amount of sense that we should be more focused on what we can do for our spouse (including anticipating their needs) than what they can do for us.  However, this struck me as something rather more extreme.